# filter coordinates for specific \addplot

Tags: pgfplots

I want to use `\addplot` twice and I want to filter the x values in one of them. However, `x filter/.code={...}` goes into the `axis` options and thus is applied to all `\addplot`s. How can I select a specific `\addplot`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x filter/.code={\pgfmathadd{#1}{0.5}}]
\addplot coordinates { %use `x filter' only here,
(4,0)
(6,1)
};
\addplot coordinates {%but not here !!
(6.5,0)
(4.4,1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the `x filter` to the `addplot` options.

For reference: As mentioned in your other question, [compilation error with `legend entries={...}` and `y filter/.code={...}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154228/compilation-error-with-legend-entries-and-y-filter-code), errors can occur when `#1` is used here. Workaround suggested in manual is to use `\pgfmathresult` instead of `#1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [x filter/.code={\pgfmathadd{#1}{0.5}},blue,mark=*] coordinates { %use `x filter' only here,
(4,0)
(6,1)
};
\addplot  coordinates {%but not here !!
(6.5,0)
(4.4,1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]