# compilation error with `legend entries={...}` and `y filter/.code={...}`

Tags: pgfplots, errors

The following example doesn't compile, unless I remove either the `y filter/.code={...}` or the `[legend entries={...}]` option: Is it a bug?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend entries={$T_2$}]
\addplot [
  black, mark=o,
  y filter/.code={\pgfmathadd{#1}{-273.15}}
] table [x index=0, y index=2] {
% Z [ m ], T_1 [ K ], T_2 [ K ], T_3 [ K ]
8.82351398e-03 5.59299194e+02 5.59402649e+02 5.59561707e+02
6.17647171e-02 5.59371826e+02 5.59538818e+02 5.59796021e+02
1.14705920e-01 5.59466797e+02 5.59699219e+02 5.60057556e+02
1.67647123e-01 5.59586304e+02 5.59883911e+02 5.60343323e+02
2.20588207e-01 5.59727844e+02 5.60091980e+02 5.60654602e+02
2.73529410e-01 5.59903564e+02 5.60327087e+02 5.60982483e+02
3.26470613e-01 5.60062622e+02 5.60573364e+02 5.61363403e+02
3.79411817e-01 5.60223877e+02 5.60828369e+02 5.61762695e+02
4.32352901e-01 5.60391724e+02 5.61091370e+02 5.62172058e+02
};
\end{axis}[
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jake, I have no objections against closing the topic.

Answer (score 6):

When using `y filter` in the options of an `\addplot` command (as opposed to in the `axis` options), you need to use `\pgfmathresult` to refer to the current value, not `#1`.

From the manual:

> Note that you can provide different `x filter`/`y filter` arguments to
>   each `\addplot` command. It seems there are only problems with the `#1`
>   argument, and I haven’t yet found out why. Please use `\pgfmathresult`
>   in place of `#1` if you provide `\addplot[x filter/.code={...}]`.

Comment: Good to know. BTW, if I omit `legend entries={}` then `#1` *does* work! Anyways, thanks a lot! It drove me almost nuts!